# Is 13.10 the latest version of Xubuntu?

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu

And when does the next version of it come out? And will I get a notice of all future versions and the ability to upgrade?

Comment: read this https://wiki.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1):

[Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/about/) is a [derivative](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/derivatives) of Ubuntu - basically it is Ubuntu pre-installed with the [Xfce](http://www.xfce.org/) desktop.

Yes, Ubuntu 13.10 is the latest release of Ubuntu *(released October 2013, support ends July 2014)*. There is also 12.04.4 is a LTS (Long Term Support) so will be supported for longer *(released February 2014, support ends April 2017)*

Ubuntu 14.04 is the next release of Ubuntu, due in April 2014. After, in July, 13.10 with become End Of Life, and will no longer be supported. For more on Ubuntu releases, see [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).

To upgrade to the next version, you can using [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu/110483#110483), or [these instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade) when they are updated after 14.04 is released. So when 14.04 is released, you can  upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04.